# How to show type first balance on one line and prevent repeating using crystal report

Tags: sql-server, function, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, formula

**How to show (first balance ) on one line summarized using crystal report as following**

```
1           first balance           9000

InvoiceNo        type               debit   
1           first balance           2000
2           first balance           3000
3           first balance           4000
4           end balance             7000
5           SalesInvoice            8500
```

**I need to show type (first balance) on one line with summarized
so that what i need actually when type = first balance show on one line with sumarized debit using crystal report .**

**This data saved on sql server 2012 .**

Comment: do a group section at the invoice level and display summary.

Comment: can you show more details answer if possible

Comment: below invoiceNo type and credit should be a group section so you can only see 1 first type of each kind and display summary debit